# How to convert varchar format into integer format with NULLs in column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a column with a varchar(255) format.
The column has number values and NULL values.
I need to convert the column to an integer format, but it fails because of the NULL values.
I have looked it up online and this issue is stated many places. But I can't seem to find the right solution. The solution has to work in a Microsoft SQL server enviroment.

I have tried this:

`CAST(varcharname AS INT) AS  varname`

`CAST(CASE WHEN varcharname IS NOT NULL THEN varcharname ELSE NULL END AS INT) AS varname`

`CAST(NULLIF(varcharname , '') AS INT) AS varname`

`CAST(NULLIF(varcharname , NULL) AS INT) AS varname`

Comment: Are the values actual `NULL` or strings containing the text `NULL`? - there is no issue converting actual `NULL`s to `int` and no special logic needed.

Comment: What happens if you try this: [select varcharname * 1 from table1]. I've seen this hack work.

Comment: Also what do you mean " it fails because of the NULL values"? Do you get an error? If so what? It is by no means clear that you aren't just trying to insert the result into a column disallowing nulls from the information given so far...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the null values, and I can prove it:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6734d0967eae022b0af2ee3a2b694db

More likely there is something else in the column that fails the conversion. Perhaps some whitespace? Remember that an empty string is not the same as NULL, and a string with only whitespace is not the same as an empty string.

Try this:

```
cast(nullif(rtrim(varcharname),'') as int)
```

---

One other thing to consider is if there is more data in the column and you are restricting results with a `WHERE` clause.

For example, let's say you have this data:

| id | varcharname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | '1' |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | '3' |
| 4 | '4' |
| 5 | 'Five' |

You may have a query with `WHERE` clause condition like this:

```
SELECT cast(varcharname as int) WHERE id <> 5
```

hoping to get results like this:

| ~ |
| --- |
| 1 |
| NULL |
| 3 |
| 4 |

This solution will often (not always!) still fail, because ***the database may decide it's more efficient to apply the cast before the WHERE clause.***

In this case (or if the earlier solution don't work) you can use [TRY_CAST()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

However, rather than use `TRY_CAST()` to merely smooth over your errors, first look to find out which rows/values are causing the errors (so you can fix them, and also fix whatever upstream process saved the bad data):

```
SELECT [id], varcharname
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE TRY_CAST(varcharname as int) IS NULL and varcharname IS NOT NULL
```

Finally, remember it's **very poor practice** to use varchar columns to store number (or date) data in the first place, to the point I consider such schemas to be *broken*.